# I do not know how to use command prompt for mysql using

Tags: mysql, sql, cmd

Sometimes you come across programmers use command prompt(cmd) to write sql queries.How to configure it?The answer below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. You have to create your service (which you can see by clicking right start menu bar and task manager). To create your service you have to open cmd as an adminstrator. Then write `cd where/your/ sql/bin/`. After that, write `mysqld -install` - you should see `service succesfully installed`.
2. Go to services from task manager, find mysql, right click it and click start.
3. Go to cmd, write `cd where/your/ sql/bin/`, and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
4. Write `mysql -u root` (if it is not protected with password, if so then add `-p`).

Then you will be able to use SQL queries.

Please see the Mysql Manual page [The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html) for a reference.

Comment: one uses it to (1)  gets into the mysql shell and perform operations ... for instance I have a shell sitting here open for days I execute things against. or (2) runs scripts via command line and returns to command line upon script completion with `-e` option or `<`. Manual page [Over Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html)

Answer (score 1):

> The answer below.

Not sure you are asking question (or) giving answer. BTW, you can use `mysql.exe` utility to connect to your `MySQL` DB server in command prompt like

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```

For more information See [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html)